# Run OGRE SDK failed

Tags: graphics, 3d, ogre3d, ogre

I am new to Ogre. I downloaded OgreSDK_vc9_v1-7-4 and I want to run it using VS2008. After  I extract the source code from it, I open folder OgreSDK_vc9_v1-7-4\Samples\Browser. It builds and runs successfully.

But then an error dialog appears.The information is :

```
ERROR:
These requested sample plugins were either missing, corrupt or invalid.
_:.\Sample_BezierPatch_d
_:.\Sample_BSP_d
etc
```

[image]

I did this as the book "OGRE 3D 1.7 Beginner's Guide" said. Have I missed something?

Comment: What did you build exactly. Did you build the entire ogre.sln solution?

Comment: @Bart Thanks.I rebuild the entire ogre and it is OK now.

Comment: Great. Glad that helped. I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building Ogre, make sure you build the entire solution. That is, the main Ogre.sln in the main folder. The problem you're seeing is most likely due to some components not getting built when you perform only a partial build.