# OGRE sample failed

Tags: xcode5, ogre

I am new to Ogre. When I run ogre sample from xcode the following error dialog appears.

```
These requested sample plugins were either missing, corrupt or invalid.
_:.\Sample_BezierPatch_d
_:.\Sample_BSP_d
```

etc

Comment: I know nothing of Ogre: but I think this might be a duplicate of this existing StackOverFlow Post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026319/run-ogre-sdk-failed

Comment: How are you running the samples? Are yous tarting the OgreSampleBrowser? Do the other samples work, just not these two?

Comment: I'm starting OgreSampleBrowser but when he is starts there are no samples and print message "These requested sample plugins were either missing, corrupt or invalid". Other samples not working also.

Answer (score 1):

1. Search for the file `plugins.cfg` in your project folder
2. Open the file and check for entries `Sample_BezierPatch_d` and `Sample_BSP_d`
3. If you can't find them you need to add both of those entries and make sure the plugins are available in the path mentioned in the file